# how to get my captions placed correctly?

Tags: php, jquery, css, image, html

I have an image gallery that, at the moment, displays only images. I would like the gallery to look like this (my simple test gallery):
http://jsfiddle.net/karin_A/Nmxx4/1/
i.e. caption at the center below the image.

The best I've been able to achieve so far is a gallery where the caption is placed below but to the right of the image:

[image: image example]

html image container:

```
 <div data-role="content" id="pagecontent" class="gallerycontent">
    <?= $output ?>
        </div>
```

php image output:

```
 $html .= '<a href="#imgshow" data-transition="pop" data-index="'.$i.'" data-rel="dialog" id="thumb">
        <img src="https://[url]/'.rawurlencode($this->_decode_path($xml->COM->MOVIE[$i]->attributes()->dbIcoFilename)).'" alt="'.$xml->COM->MOVIE[$i]->attributes()->nameS.'" class="imgAlt">
        </a>';
```

jQuery adds wrapping border and caption:

```
$.each($("img"), function() {
        $(this).wrap('<div class="wrapper"/>');
    });
    $.each($("img.imgAlt"), function() {
        $(this).after($(this).attr("alt"));
    });
```

css:

```
#pagecontent {
text-align:center;
font-size:12px;
color:#000;
text-decoration:none;
}

.wrapper{
    float:left;
    padding:0.2em;
    border: 1px solid #C0C0C0;
    margin:10px;
}

.thumb{
    padding: 0.1em;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.gallerycontent a img { 
    margin: 0.2em;
}

.caption{
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
```

When I limit the width (width:100px;) if the wrapping border I get this result:
[image: newdump]
which, as you can see, works if the image name is really short but it sometimes isn't.

Another try:

```
$.each($("img.imgAlt"), function() {
        var title = this.alt;
        $(this).after('<div class="caption">'+ title +'</div>');
    });
```

which places the caption centered below the image, but also makes the div fill the entire page width, not only the width of the caption.

Comment: <img> tag is an self closing element so write this <img/> instead of <img></img>

Comment: I edited my code accordingly.

Comment: And you want the caption text to be at the center-below the image?

Comment: Yes, exactly! I'm now able to upload images, see above.

Comment: @Karin upvoted yesterday for that extra rep for you to be able to post images :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works. I made the new div into a new span instead:

```js
$.each($("img.imgAlt"), function() {
    var imgAlt = this.alt;
    $(this).empty().after('<span class="caption">'+ imgAlt +'</span>');
});
```

and changed the css for .caption to this:

```css
.caption{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration:none;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:80%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `clear:both` to your `.caption` CSS class

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't result in anything.

Comment: can you provide a link to the page in your app where i can see the issue?

Comment: It's not online yet, but I'll post a screenshot when I've earned one more reputation point :)

Comment: Screenshot of example in place above.

Answer (score 0):

Just define your `.caption` text to be centered automatically, like so:

```
.caption {
   text-align:center;
}
```

Edit: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Nmxx4/5/)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work with above code. It works fine in my test fiddle though. I've also tried putting image in one div, caption in one div, and both in a wrapping div and then trying to position the inner divs, but with the same result.

Comment: @Karin tried the demo once again with your CSS up top and it still looks ok, http://jsfiddle.net/Nmxx4/6/ .. can you post a test page with your code to take a look?

Comment: It looks really good in the fiddle! Maybe my real problem is the surrounding code (which I didn't write and cannot share). I'll see if I can find another way of attacking the problem and get back here later.

Comment: @Karin check the CSS with Chromes Developer Tools to see if anything is being changed by your surrounding code.

Comment: There seems to be something in jQuery mobile that disturbs my "alt" and makes it into a hyperlink. I just want it to be plain text.